# Handling response from server in Netty client

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing a JavaFX application using Netty to implement a custom protocol. There is no session state but I would like to correlate a server response to a particular outbound request (and return the result to the correct JavaFX `Task`.) So far I haven't been able to do so in the client code, because the responseFuture is a `ChannelFuture<Void>`.

```
future = tcpBoostrap.connect(address, 3333).sync();
final Channel channel = future.awaitUninterruptibly().channel();

ChannelFuture responseFuture = channel.writeAndFlush(requestBuilder.build());
responseFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {
        if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
            logger.debug("completed operation: {}", channelFuture.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

I tried looking how to configure a `PipeLine` to somehow install `ChannelHandlers` that would share the information in a shared context variable but I could not find anything significant.

Can anyone suggest the idiomatic place where I can stuff the UI Task that I can "complete" with the response in Netty?

Answer (score 0):

Netty can't do such work for you as it cannot understand pairing mechanism. On the client side you need to implement `ChannelHandler` and pass the initializer to the `.handler(handler)` method. See [Netty TimeClient example](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html#wiki-h2-4) for details. In the handler `channelRead` method process the response from the server, deserialize it and according to the mechanism specific to your application pair with previously created `Future` and complete it. The `Future` doesn't need to be necessarily Netty future as this part is completely out of Netty processing.

For the pairing I assume you use some id which you send to the server and server sends the same id back to the client. So in such case some `Map<Long, Future<?>>` would be sufficient.

Comment: So basically something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9048781/261984). Hold onto the pipeline used in the initializer and `addLast` a clientHandler that holds a ref to the Task

Comment: @Eddy : Partially yes, in the way they construct the handler. But note that the handler is created for the connection (or can be even shared) so it's not possible to give it a reference to Request/Future if you reuse the same connection for many requests. You need to maintain map of request ids to the SettableFuture or callback which you then complete upon receiving the appropriate response.